# A formula to calculate the total overlap area of two polygons?

Tags: geometry, polygons

Suppose I have two polygons that overlap as shown

[image]

Given the coordinate for each vertex, is there a formula I can use to find the total area that the polygons share with each other?

```
Polygon 1
24.99593, -70.98575
24.99411, -70.98534
24.99353, -70.9829
24.99539, -70.98179
24.99671, -70.98414

Polygon 2
24.99585, -70.98294
24.99573, -70.98273
24.99597, -70.9814
24.9949, -70.98157
24.9951, -70.98263
24.99491, -70.98276
24.99474, -70.98241
24.99478, -70.98101
24.99648, -70.98127
24.99683, -70.98223
24.99588, -70.98331
```

Comment: I think the only way is to compute the intersection. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Polygon_clipping_algorithms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no shortcut to this computation, which is related to the construction of the intersection of the polygons. Anyway, you don't need all the steps.

A possible way is to sort all vertices vertically, and consider all the horizontal slices between two vertices.

In such a slice, both shapes are seen as a set of trapezoids, and computing the area common to these trapezoids is manageable.

This is known as a sweepline algorithm.

[image]

Comment: There are lots of details in "computing the area common to these trapezoids is manageable"...

Comment: @lhf: those details are manageable. There are $4$ overlap configurations for two segments, hence $16$ for two trapezoids and most of them are trivial.